# MapMatching using GPS data

Tags: qgis, gps, map-matching

I have GPS data from multiple users and multiple routes and I'd like match them into the actual route using QGIS, because there are some outline points.
My data is a csv file with 2.989 points, containing user-id, route-id, modality of transportation, time and date, x and y coordinates, accuracy, speed and heading from the GPS.
I tried to do that with the Offline-MapMatching plugin, but it seems that it has some bug or something and doesn't work.
When using the plugin, I selected a road layer that I have as a network layer, the GPS points as the trajectory layer and for the trajectory ID I chose the time column from the points. I didn't change the maximum search distance and fast matching type for the plugin to run it.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! Please edit your post with more information - what *exactly* did you try, and how did it fail? What do your data look like?

Comment: Hey there! I did some alterations in the question that might help

Comment: What is the bug "os smth"?

Comment: Misspelling! Sorry for that

Comment: Are you getting an error message from the plugin when it runs?

Comment: No, the script keeps running for a long time and doesn't show any resuts.